# backup command issue from linux server using ssh

Tags: ssh, mysql, database-backups

I am mewbie for ssh and mysql commanding.
I have a issue with taking backup from one linux server to another linux server using passwordless authentication. I already generated the key for passwordless authentication and upload it to another server.

I have used this command

```
[user1@server1 ~]$ mysqldump -u dbuser -p"dbpwd" --opt  dbname | gzip -c | ssh  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/...../known_hosts -l deploy -i  /...../id_rsa -v  user2@server2  "/bin/cat > user2@server2:/......./test.sql.gz" 2>&1
```

Now when I run the command in SSH, I got the below error

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_20082' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_20082' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/indus33/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I have googled a lot but no solution helped me.

If anyone have query about this frequenkly ask me.

please help me to solve this issue.

**updated**

I run the command

[user@server1 ~]$ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/..../known_hosts -l deploy -i /..../id_rsa -v user2@server2

**error**

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /.../ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to server2IP [server2IP] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /......./id_rsa type 1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'server2IP' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /......./known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_20082' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_20082' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /....../id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
Last login: Mon Sep 30 03:25:52 2013 from server1
user2@server2 [~]#
```

hope the issue will be clear for all.....

Comment: What happens exactly (hangup/exit/signalX)?Can you check the server side logs?

Comment: I did not check any server side logs.

Comment: Maybe can you paste the exact command line, and the contents of the scripts? (you can replace the real backup command with an ls for example, It is easier to debug in smaller chunks.)

Comment: now see the updated question

Comment: I searched on net and found only id_rsa for command

Comment: Did you append the id_rsa.pub file to the user2@server2 .ssh/authenticated_keys file? Can you try only the ssh part alone. Does it work? (SSH is sensible about the permissions of this file also.)

Comment: yes I did copy the id_rsa.pub on user2@server2 and when I connect server2 from server1 using then its working and I reache into server2 from server1 without providing password.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38417/discussion-between-ghost-answer-and-lajos-veres)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to first create a authorized_keys at server2

```
 touch /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
 chmod 600 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Then copy content of id_rsa.pub to the server to

```
[user1@server1 ~]$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user2@server2 "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Then issue the below mysqldump command on server1

```
[user1@server1 ~]$ mysqldump -u dbuser -p"dbpwd" --opt  dbname | gzip -c | ssh user2@server2 "/bin/cat > /your_path/test.sql.gz" 2>&
```

Comment: Have you appended your id_rsa.pub of server1 to the authorized_keys file of server2? And after that use the below command to dump the db "mysqldump -u dbuser -p"dbpwd" --opt  dbname | gzip -c | ssh user2@server2 "/bin/cat > /your_path/test.sql.gz" 2>&"

Comment: yes, I already added this in authorized_keys file on server2.

Comment: Are you able to ssh to that server2 from server1 Just use this command "ssh server2". Don't use any option.